# database is locked in getReadableDatabase() android

Tags: android, sqlite

In my app I am getting database is locked.

I tried using solutions provided in other posts but could not found suitable solution this is why I am posting this question.

Here is the onCreate

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this.getApplicationContext());
        dialoge = new Progress_Dialog(this);
        dialoge.setCancelable(false);
        try {
            db.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and here is the create database method

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{     
            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();     
            if(!dbExist){
                this.getReadableDatabase();     
                try {     
                    copyDataBase();
                } catch (IOException e) {     
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw new Error("Error copying database");     
                }
            }
        }
```

and below is the checkdatabase method

```
 private boolean checkDataBase(){     
            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
            try{
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

                String myPath2 = DB_PATH + DB_NAME2;

                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, 
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

                if(checkDB != null){
                    checkDB.close();

                }
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath2, null, 
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

            }catch(SQLiteException e){
        //      e.printStackTrace();
                //database does't exist yet.
                System.out.print("SQLiteException   "+e.toString());
            }
            if(checkDB != null){
                checkDB.close();

            }
            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "locking" is occurring because you are attempting to open multiple `SQLiteDatabase` instances. Make your `SQLiteDatabase` a singleton as described in this [post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html).

Comment: Your solution seems to be nice let me use it and verify it whether it solved my problem or not but +1 for the nice information in the post :)

Answer (score -4):

change this method  this.getReadableDatabase();  to this.getWritableDatabase();

it will work...

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: which purpose we created database like only readable or writable. in ur code database purpose is read and write so its mandatory to call this.getWritableDatabase(); please change to accordingly and run it. ur code is checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, 
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

Comment: Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and writing. The first time this is called, the database will be opened and onCreate(SQLiteDatabase), onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int) and/or onOpen(SQLiteDatabase) will be called. 

Once opened successfully, the database is cached, so you can call this method every time you need to write to the database. (Make sure to call close() when you no longer need the database.) Errors such as bad permissions or a full disk may cause this method to fail, but future attempts may succeed if the problem is fixed.